# MYSQL Select items in list from subquery

Tags: mysql

Thanks in advance for any help you guys can offer.  I have been stuck on this one for a few hours this morning and nothing I search for seems to help.

I am storing a list of accounts associated with a client as a string in my database like this:

```
   | li.client_accounts   |
   +-----+----------------+
   |ID   |facility        |
   +-----+----------------+
   |23   |1010, 1020, 1025|
   +-----+----------------+
```

I am trying to select appointments from another database where the account number is in the list using a sub query like this:

```
    SELECT * FROM li_appointments.li_appointments
    where app_client_id in (select facility from li_client_accounts where id = 23)
```

However my results are only showing the appointments with a client_id of 1010, and ignoring the rest.  What do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: Are you at all able to change the design of your tables? Sticking multiple values into a single field violates first normal form - there's a reason why queries like this don't work well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not working because the `IN` clause expects a list of fields. However, in your case, `facility` is a string of comma separated values, and not a queriable list. This is bad design. You need to make your client_accounts table atomic, like :

```
   | li.client_accounts   |
   +-----+----------------+
   |client_ID   |facility |
   +-----+----------------+
   |23   |1010|
   |23   |1015|
   |23   |1020|
   +-----+----------------+
```

Comment: You are right.  I think I was trying to be lazy with my php code.  Thanks for pushing me in the right direction,

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `IN()` like that.

What you are actually getting is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM li_appointments.li_appointments
    where app_client_id in ('1010, 1020, 1025')
```

This is obviously not what you want.

You need to seriously think about normalizing your `facility` column if you want to use it in a relational manner.